# bash function which pipes input through filter in some cases, passes input through unchanged otherwise

Tags: bash

I want my bash function `process` to filter input conditionally.

```
#!/bin/bash

ARG="$1"

function process
{
    if [ "unique" == "$ARG" ];
    then
        sort | uniq
    else
        :
    fi
}

echo -e "a\na\na\nb\nc\nb\na" | process
```

If I run this with `bash example.sh unique` I get the filtered output. If I omit the `unique` argument I get *no* output. I want `process` to pass on its input *unchanged* if the `unique` argument is not given.

What's an elegant way to do this?

Comment: pass on its input unchanged  - Where? do you want to reuse the string later in the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*an elegant way to do this* is defining a function as below,

```
process()
  case ${1-} in
  (unique) sort -u ;;
  (*     ) cat
  esac
```

and using it like:

```
printf 'a\na\na\nb\nc\nb\na\n' | process unique
printf 'a\na\na\nb\nc\nb\na\n' | process
```